# Check the modules imported into an interactive console

Tags: python

I'm testing in Ipython and want to acknowledge of modules and packages already imported,

Firstly I tried `locals` and `globals`,

```
In [22]: len(globals())
Out[22]: 46

In [23]: len(locals())
Out[23]: 48
```

I have to lookup manually.

How to list the imported modules exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code works

```
import sys
print([i for i in globals() if i in sys.modules.keys()])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just:

```
print(dir())
```

for example

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(dir())
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> import csv
>>> import json
>>> print(dir())
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'csv', 'json']
>>>
```

Comment: he mentioned, he wants to know imported modules exclusively. this gives exhaustive list